# .NET Core issue: System.OperationCanceledException when hosted in IIS

Tags: api, .net-core

My program.cs file in .NET Core 3.1 is like this I am creating web API in .net core but I am getting this error when hosted on server in IIS. API is working fine when hosted locally.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
 var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config")).GetLogger();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        
}

        public static  IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                }).ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                })
              .UseNLog();
    }
```

> System.OperationCanceledException:  at program.cs error

I am getting this error with stack trace like:

> ```
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>    at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
>    at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken
> ```
>
> cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.WaitForShutdownAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
> host)

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same error, and I was trying to see what might cause it.

I came across this link [with the same issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17221)

and the thing that jumped out at me was the "non-graceful shutdown". To test, I recycled the application website on IIS, which did not trigger the error. I then tried turning off the app pool via IIS, and DID trigger the exception.
This leads me to believe it has something to do with a task running inside the application that is cut short when the non-graceful shutdown occurs.
In my case, I have a HostedService running in the background of my application, do you have something similar in yours?

Comment: no i have not any hosted service in the background...did you figured it out ultimately?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a root cause.

Comment: Check out this link: https://andrewlock.net/extending-the-shutdown-timeout-setting-to-ensure-graceful-ihostedservice-shutdown/ I know you said you don't have a background service, but it might be related to an open task that you might be unaware of.